# Css - Adjust the width of the box to the text

Tags: css

I need to adjust the width of the box to the text

This is the html code:

```
<span class="box">Testing content of the box</span>
```

This is the css code:

```
.box {
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff9c00;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Would be this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

Always should to have the same padding left and right regardless of the size of the text.

How could i do it?

Comment: What's wrong with the above code? as far as I can tell, it should do what you want

Comment: @Pete is right... if it is `inline` then you have an issue with background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.box {
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff9c00;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
  max-width:400px;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<span class="box">Content</span>

<span class="box">Content, and even more content and even more content and even more content and even more content and even more content </span>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Please mark it as a correct answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` in combination with `clear: both`

```css
.box {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff9c00;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<span class="box">Content</span>

<span class="box">Content, and even more content</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`width: auto;` should do the trick here

```css
.box {
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff9c00;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="box">Testing content of the box</span>

<span class="box">Testing content of the box Testing content of the box Testing content of the box Testing content of the box </span>
```

Comment: width auto makes absolutely no difference - remove it and run your snippet and you will see the same result

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width` and `max-width` to set minimum and maximum size of divisions.

```css
.box {
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ff9c00;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
  max-width:400px;
}
```

```html
<span class="box">Content</span>

<span class="box">Content, and even more content and even more content and even more content and even more content and even more content </span>
```